# Replece/Modify specific words in String In Java

Tags: java, string

What is the simplest way to add new signs in String?

For example:

```
String a = My test Zstring to see Zwhat happen;
result = My test $Zstring$ to see $Zwhat$ happen;
```

I want to add `$` sign at the beginning and at the end of all words in String which starts with uppercase Z.

Comment: Is it Java or JavaScript?

Comment: Please use the code formatting option and clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try regex like this (Java). JS also has similar syntax. You ahve to use `replace()` with `\..\` and single `\w+` instead of `\\w+`:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String a = "My test Zstring to see Zwhat happen;";
    System.out.println(a.replaceAll("\\b(Z\\w+)\\b", "\\$$1\\$"));

}

O/P :
My test $Zstring$ to see $Zwhat$ happen;
```

Explanation :

> `\\b` --> ensures word boundary
>
> `()` --> captures strings starting
>   with `Z`
>
> `$1` --> means first captured group `\\$` --> means the
>   character `$` literally. Since it has special meaning, it has to be
>   escaped using `\\`

Comment: This will work, but if this is an assignment your teacher will surely know that you haven't done this code

Comment: Do you know what should i do if i wanna replace @ sign ?

Answer (score 0):

This will suit your purpose:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "My test Zstring to see Zwhat happen";
        int i,n;
        n = data.length();
        char charAtI;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            charAtI = data.charAt(i);
            if (charAtI == 'Z') {
                data = data.substring(0, i-1) + " $" + data.substring(i, data.length());
                while (charAtI != ' ') {
                    charAtI = data.charAt(i);
                    i++;
                }
                data = data.substring(0, i-1) + "$ " + data.substring(i, data.length());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(data);
  }
```

Input: `My test Zstring to see Zwhat happen`
Output: `My test $Zstring$ to see $Zwhat$ happen`

I believe it is an assignment so it uses simple loops and basic stuff. Also this is not very performance oriented solution.